# Unable to update linux headers, remains at 0%

Tags: apt, package-management, updates

I installed Ubuntu 18.04. When I try to install Java or try to update with `sudo apt update` it shows this:

```
leonardo@lherrera:~$ sudo apt update
[sudo] password for leonardo: 
Hit:1 file:/var/cuda-repo-10-0-local-10.0.130-410.48  InRelease
Ign:1 file:/var/cuda-repo-10-0-local-10.0.130-410.48  InRelease
Hit:2 file:/var/cuda-repo-10-0-local-10.0.130-410.48  Release [574 B]
Hit:2 file:/var/cuda-repo-10-0-local-10.0.130-410.48  Release [574 B]
Ign:4 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                   
Obj:5 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release                     
Obj:7 http://ppa.launchpad.net/maarten-fonville/ppa/ubuntu bionic InRelease    
Err:8 http://192.168.1.245/ubuntu bionic InRelease                             
  Connection failed [IP: 192.168.1.245 80]
Reading package list... Done
Building adependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
1 package can be upgraded. Run "apt list --upgradable" to see it.
W: Failed to fetch http://192.168.1.245/ubuntu/dists/bionic InRelease  
  Connection failed [IP: 192.168.1.245 80]  
W: Some index files could not be downloaded, were omitted, or old ones were used instead.
```

Comment: Please get the error messages in english by doing `env LANG=C sudo apt update`, so the unilingual english users of AskUbuntu can help you.

Answer (score 4):

There is a problem with the repository at 192.168.1.245 (which is a private internal IPv4 address only).  This is the (English translated) error message:

```
Err: 8 http://192.168.1.245/ubuntu bionic InRelease
  The connection failed [IP: 192.168.1.245 80] 
...
W: Failed to obtain http://192.168.1.245/ubuntu/dists/bionic/InRelease The connection failed [IP: 192.168.1.245 80]
```

The issue lies at that server that's in your `/etc/apt/sources.list` file or in a file within `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` files somewhere.

You can solve this by commenting out the line that refers to that IP address and then running the update process again.  However, if this is supposed to be an actual repository server, then you need to go fix that server or let whoever runs it know it needs fixing.